# Using type="A" in unordered list <ul>

Tags: html

In unordered list **type** attributes accepts disc,square, circle etc as its value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul. Today I came across a code where **type="A"** was given in the  tag and it was working fine. I want to  Its shows the output like ordered list only.I know type has been deprecated and its wrong using ordered list functionality within ul tag but can anyone tell me why this is happening? If that is the case, why we use ordered list then

```
<ul type="A">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Output:

```
A.Coffee
B.Tea
C.Milk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real difference between `ul` and `ol` elements is that `ul` is rendered as a bulleted list by default, whereas `ol` is rendered as a numbered list by default. This is what really happens in browsers. There is no reason to expect search engines to make any distinction between them (if they care about list markup at all). In specifications, various descriptions are given, but such “semantics” don’t affect software.

On a closer look, there’s the difference that different element nodes are constructed, and there are differences between browsers in dealing with `type` attribute values that are not allowed by the specifications.

Using just `<ul type="A">` is unnecessarily risky, due to the browser differences. A safer way is to use `<ul type="A" style="list-style-type: upper-alpha">`. (Omit `type="A"` if compliance to specifications is more important than taking into account the possibility of non-CSS rendering.)

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers show this behaviour (see e.g. http://browsershots.org/).

This could be called a bug in the browsers that display the `<ul>` as a `<ol>`, but it can be argued either way: when getting an invalid page (mismatch between tag and attribute), should the tag be trusted and the attribute be ignored or vice-versa?

Comment: Yeah I checked it. IE and Firefox is taking that as an ordered list while chrome is still taking it as undordered one only. http://jsfiddle.net/uAqQs/ I think that's why they are deprecated it.